# Is it possible to add chords or curved lines to an arc visualization with d3.js? (Without using chord.groups)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, chord-diagram

I have created an arc visualization that is a semi-circle with about 74 path elements on it, each representing a country and it's "arcValue" (expressed as the height of each path):

http://jsfiddle.net/developerAndADj/2DYrQ/

I'm looking to add chords to the visualization for countries that have a productCount > 0. Each chord would go from each it's corresponding path element to a path that sits below the arc.

I am trying to accomplish two things:

1. Show that certain countries have a product count and others do not.
2. Have curved lines or chords that represent these product counts.

So far, I have been able to use an additional arc inside of the one in the above fiddle that goes from the center of the semi-circle to each path element, however the curved effect is not there.

I have also managed to create chords based off of the product count for each country, however, I am unable to get the chords to line up with it's corresponding country. Here is my code to generate the cords:

```
// Initialize the square matrix
var cDataMatrix = [];
for(var h = 0; h < data.length; h++){
  cDataMatrix[h] = [];

  for(var k = 0; k < data.length; k++){
    cDataMatrix[h][k] = 0;
  }
}

// Fill the matrix with product count values
data.forEach(function(d){
  for(var a = 0; a < productVals.length; a++){
    if(d.productCount){
      cDataMatrix[d.id][d.id] = d.productCount;
    } 
  }
});

// Generate the chord layout
var chord = d3.layout.chord()
  .padding(.1)
  .matrix(cDataMatrix);

var ch = d3.svg.chord()
  .radius(300)
  .startAngle(function(d, i){
    return arcScale(i*(Math.PI/179.2));
  })
  .endAngle(function(d, i){
    var degree = i+0.8;
    return arcScale(degree*(Math.PI/179.2));
  });

// Draw the chords on the arc
var chords = indArcBody.append("g")
  .attr("class", "chords");

chords.selectAll("path.chord")
  .data(chord.chords)
  .enter().append("svg:path")
  .attr("class", "chord")
  .style("fill", "#000")
  .attr("d", ch);
```

Here is a demo of it:
http://jsfiddle.net/developerAndADj/68WRT/

Is it possible to line up each chord to it's respective path element? Also, is it possible to use chords or curved lines that go from the inner radius of each path element to a path that sits below the arc, or any specified coordinate in the SVG?

Thanks for any feedback!